# wxpython figure.canvas.mpl_connect() not work for interactive plot

Tags: wxpython

```
import wx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import rand
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wx import NavigationToolbar2Wx
from matplotlib.figure import Figure


class CanvasPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.figure, self.ax = plt.subplots()
        self.x, self.y, self.c, self.s = rand(4, 100)
        self.ax.scatter(self.x, self.y, 100 * self.s, self.c, picker=True)
        self.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', self.onpick3)
        # plt.show()


        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.figure)
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.canvas, 1, wx.RIGHT | wx.GROW)
        self.SetSizerAndFit(self.sizer)

    def onpick3(self, event):
        ind = event.ind
        print('onpick3 scatter:', ind, np.take(self.x, ind), np.take(self.y, ind))


class BetaFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super().__init__(parent, -1, title=title, size=(1000, 1000),
                         style=wx.MINIMIZE_BOX | wx.RESIZE_BORDER | wx.SYSTEM_MENU |
                               wx.CAPTION | wx.CLOSE_BOX | wx.CLIP_CHILDREN)

        self.initpos = 300
        self.sp = wx.SplitterWindow(self)
        self.p1 = wx.Panel(self.sp, style=wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)
        self.p2 = wx.Panel(self.sp, style=wx.SUNKEN_BORDER, name='Plot')
        self.p1.SetBackgroundColour('light')
        self.p2.SetBackgroundColour('light')
        self.sp.SplitVertically(self.p1, self.p2, self.initpos)
        self.Centre()

        CanvasPanel(self.p2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = BetaFrame(None, 'Beta Version')
    frame.Show()
    app.SetTopWindow(frame)
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]
I tried to use the figure.canvas.mpl_connect() in matplotlib to build an interactive plot in a panel, but failed. The code below works well without plotting on a panel. The difference is on a panle, the plt.show() cannot be used. Does figure.canvas.mpl_connect() work on wxpython? Or there are other ways to make interactive plot? Thanks!

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import rand
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class CanvasPanel:
    def __init__(self):
        # self.figure = Figure()
        self.figure, self.ax = plt.subplots()
        self.x, self.y, self.c, self.s = rand(4, 100)
        self.ax.scatter(self.x, self.y, 100 * self.s, self.c, picker=True)
        self.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', self.onpick3)
        plt.show()

    def onpick3(self, event):
        ind = event.ind
        print('onpick3 scatter:', ind, np.take(self.x, ind), np.take(self.y, ind))
        
CanvasPanel()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run a mile when faced with plotting with matplotlib but I'm pretty sure you are meant to connect to the `FigureCanvas` not the `figure` thrown out by `plt.subplots`, although I'm happy to be corrected, as I said, I'm an unhappy camper in the forest of matplotlib.

The result would be:

```
import wx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import rand
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wx import NavigationToolbar2Wx
from matplotlib.figure import Figure


class CanvasPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.figure, self.ax = plt.subplots()
        self.x, self.y, self.c, self.s = rand(4, 100)
        self.ax.scatter(self.x, self.y, 100 * self.s, self.c, picker=True)
        # plt.show()


        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.figure)
        self.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', self.onpick3)
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.canvas, 1, wx.RIGHT | wx.GROW)
        self.SetSizerAndFit(self.sizer)

    def onpick3(self, event):
        ind = event.ind
        print('onpick3 scatter:', ind, np.take(self.x, ind), np.take(self.y, ind))


class BetaFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super().__init__(parent, -1, title=title, size=(1000, 1000),
                         style=wx.MINIMIZE_BOX | wx.RESIZE_BORDER | wx.SYSTEM_MENU |
                               wx.CAPTION | wx.CLOSE_BOX | wx.CLIP_CHILDREN)

        self.initpos = 300
        self.sp = wx.SplitterWindow(self)
        self.p1 = wx.Panel(self.sp, style=wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)
        self.p2 = wx.Panel(self.sp, style=wx.SUNKEN_BORDER, name='Plot')
        self.p1.SetBackgroundColour('light')
        self.p2.SetBackgroundColour('light')
        self.sp.SplitVertically(self.p1, self.p2, self.initpos)
        self.Centre()

        CanvasPanel(self.p2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = BetaFrame(None, 'Beta Version')
    frame.Show()
    app.SetTopWindow(frame)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Now click on a coloured dot.

```
onpick3 scatter: [7] [0.18704031] [0.43573093]
onpick3 scatter: [11] [0.19506781] [0.79896204]
onpick3 scatter: [71] [0.80362554] [0.9426998]
onpick3 scatter: [40 41] [0.78295576 0.76609123] [0.92129472 0.94352157]
onpick3 scatter: [40] [0.78295576] [0.92129472]
onpick3 scatter: [94] [0.94643354] [0.0547319]
onpick3 scatter: [26 37] [0.73187773 0.73352872] [0.01974885 0.05060254]
```

Comment: Rolf, you are so great! For plotting, are there other good choices except matplotlib?

Answer (score 0):

I've included a comprehensive wxPython/matplotlib integration example with wxGlade.
See here: https://github.com/wxGlade/wxGlade/tree/master/examples/matplotlib3

As Rolf wrote, this line connects the canvas:

```
self.canvas.mpl_connect( 'pick_event', self.on_pick)
```

Comment: Your github example is something of a tour de force Dietmar. I retain my position of being not only an unhappy camper but also somewhat lost in matplotlib. :) Happy Camping!

Comment: Well, I'm doing most of my plotting in my own library, which also integrates better with Office programs (WMF export).
Still, matplotlib is quite useful for many purposes. I wish the object oriented interface was easier to use. Personally, I would drop the `plt` interface...
With the github example, I tried to cover many common use cases to make it easier to get started.

Comment: Thanks for the sharing! I will study it.